# Emulator android studio cannot open application

Tags: android

My emulator has problem , I am using android studio, my emulator always waiting for target device to come online. And My emulator name become Emulator unknown emulator-5554 offline...., May I know how to solve this problem, I am using mac windows. Thanks

Comment: Unplug it and connect again.

Comment: Try creating an emulator with different API level.

Comment: not error, my android monitor not message and emulator name write Emulator unknown emulator-5554 offline. and also show not debugging process beside the Emulator unknown emulator-5554 offline.

Comment: I try other emulator also same

Comment: and after a few minute, waiting for target device to come online is disapper and the emulator still black screen

Comment: I had that same error, and it was for having open Docker at the same time as the emulator

Comment: I solve already, I turn off the computer and open again, it can run already